# Draw line in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

I new to c# and I am struggling to draw a line in a form. Here is the code I have so far.

```
Graphics g;

g = this.CreateGraphics();

Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
myPen.Width = 30;
g.DrawLine(myPen, 30, 30, 45, 65);

g.DrawLine(myPen, 1, 1, 45, 65);
```

Comment: Then what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: The line doesn't appear on the form.

Comment: OK. Which function do you put the above code in?

Comment: What happens when you run that?

Comment: I put it after the InitializeComponent() call

Comment: OK. As others mention, you should put in the Paint event handler. After you created a WinForm application, click the form to select it, open Property editor, click the small lightning icon to switch to the event tab, double click the `Paint` field. Put your code in the generated block.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try it in `OnPaint`

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics g;

            g = e.Graphics;

            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
            myPen.Width = 30;
            g.DrawLine(myPen, 30, 30, 45, 65);

            g.DrawLine(myPen, 1, 1, 45, 65);
        }
```

Comment: This worked but why does the code I provided not work its from the msdn website.

Comment: @JohnB: Your code will draw some stuff, if you have put it in the Paint event handler.

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics.  Use the `Graphics` object that is *already* available: `g = e.Graphics`

Comment: @Justin: That is not the reason why OP didn't see anything.

Comment: you should be (using Pen myPen = new Pen) { } or at least making sure to .dispose() it.

Comment: @JohnB read the remarks section of this MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx

Comment: @JohnB: Your code *will* draw something. However, if you put it in the constructor, it is drawing the line when the form is first created, but *before the form is shown*. When the form is shown, it is redrawn again, and as your code will not be executed to draw the lines, they do not appear. You need to draw the lines every time the form is repainted (they won't be "remembered"), and the correct place for this is in OnPaint().

Answer (score 5):

That's not really a question as you didn't say what you are seeing.

The correct way to do this is in your form's `Paint` event handler. Get the graphics object from the `e` argument. Try that and let us know what you see.

Answer (score 3):

You should be drawing in the Paint event of the object on which you want to draw the line. So just use the Graphics object in the `e` variable from the `EventArgs` parameter of the Paint event. Here is a VB.NET example:

```
Private Sub ExampleLinkLabel_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                   ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) _
                                   Handles lnkMyLinkLabel.Paint

    Dim lbl As LinkLabel = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    Dim pen1 As New System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Black, 1)
    Dim topLeft As New Point(0, 0)
    Dim topRight As New Point(lbl.Width - 1, 0)
    Dim bottomLeft As New Point(0, lbl.Height - 1)
    Dim bottomRight As New Point(lbl.Width - 1, lbl.Height - 1)

    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen1, topLeft, topRight)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen1, bottomLeft, bottomRight)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen1, topRight, bottomRight)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ....
    }
```

and run it from your initializer:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
    }
```